# Speed up iteration or vectorize

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, loops, vectorization

I have data (lots of attributes) for about 50 states. For each state, I want to find the combination of attributes that gives the minimum RMSE from a logistic regression. Since there are many attributes and states, I am having about 51 million combinations of state and independent variables to loop through. I have tried to write my function in numpy but I need help vectorizing it. I have something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
import statsmodels.api as sm
import itertools

rows = 20000
total_rows = 13*rows

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'state': ['a', 'b', 'c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m']*rows,
    'y_var': [random.uniform(0,1) for i in range(total_rows)],
    'school': [random.uniform(0,10) for i in range(total_rows)],
    'church': [random.uniform(11,20) for i in range(total_rows)],
    'bar': [random.uniform(2,10) for i in range(total_rows)],
    'mosque': [random.uniform(10,50) for i in range(total_rows)],
    'office': [random.uniform(0,10) for i in range(total_rows)],
    'cafe': [random.uniform(11,20) for i in range(total_rows)],
    'mall': [random.uniform(2,10) for i in range(total_rows)],
    'washroom': [random.uniform(10,50) for i in range(total_rows)],
    'bedroom': [random.uniform(0,10) for i in range(total_rows)],
    'hotel': [random.uniform(11,20) for i in range(total_rows)],
    'car': [random.uniform(2,10) for i in range(total_rows)],
    'mailroom': [random.uniform(2,10) for i in range(total_rows)],
    'motel': [random.uniform(10,50) for i in range(total_rows)],
    'bank': [random.uniform(0,10) for i in range(total_rows)],
    'trailer': [random.uniform(11,20) for i in range(total_rows)],
    'camp': [random.uniform(2,10) for i in range(total_rows)],
    'sample': [1]*int(0.8*total_rows)+ [0]*int(0.2*total_rows)
}).to_numpy()

ind_variables = [i for i in range(2,18)]
combinations = np.array(
    [np.array(b) for b in [c for i in range(len(ind_variables)+1) for c in itertools.combinations(ind_variables,i)]]
)[1:]
states = np.unique(data[:,0])

def reg_frac(state, ind_vars):
    
    try:
        
        x_train, y_train = sm.add_constant(np.array(data[(data[:,18] == 1) & (data[:,0] == state)][:,ind_vars], dtype=float)), np.array(data[(data[:,18] == 1) & (data[:,0] == state), 1], dtype=float)
        x_test, y_test = sm.add_constant(np.array(data[(data[:,18] == 0) & (data[:,0] == state)][:,ind_vars], dtype=float)), data[(data[:,18] == 0) & (data[:,0] == state), 1]

        model = sm.Logit(y_train, x_train).fit(cov_type='HC0', disp=False)      

        rmse = np.sqrt(np.square(np.subtract(y_test, model.predict(x_test))).mean())
        
    except:
        rmse = np.nan
        
    return [state, ind_vars, rmse]
```

I have tried itertools, itertuples, map etc and they are all slow. Is there an efficient way to loop through all states and independent variables without having to leave it for hours? Also can I get help vectorizing the function? I believe that can speed things up. Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to select features for LR? Isn't state just a categorical, how are you encoding it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to optimize these types of things which depend on lots of factors so it will involve some trial and error. Some quick methods would be to try using [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org/) and JIT compile it. You can also vectorize with Numba which will give the most speed up, and allow GPU compilation if you have that.

Additionally, creating numpy arrays is expensive, so doing so in your add_constant part is pretty costly. Also, since your data is already a numpy array, you don't need to cast subsets of it into an array in that line.

For the most speed up you would probably have to turn to a compiled method like Cython, but that will take a lot of work; versus Numba being very quick and easy.

Along with @Dan's comment, there are known methods for feature selection in LR which are much more efficient than testing every combination. Check out Sklearns [Kbest](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html)

Comment: `sklearn's` logistic regression doesn't have support for continuous y variables ranging between 0 and 1.

Comment: That is not necessary to what I suggested. Kbest does not care if you use one of the built in methods or your own. Also if you are trying to get a continuous y variable from logistic regression, you are using it incorrectly. Everything should be 1 or 0 for the training set for LR. You get values in between based on predictions

Comment: Because when using LR and getting a value between 0 and 1 this can be considered the "probability" that the output is that value, based on the training data